# How to run in parallel two child command from a parent one?

Tags: perl

I need to run two perl scripts from one in parallel. How can I accomplish this?

Currently, I have a file with

```
system("perl command1.pl command2.pl");
```

Commands are executed in sequence and until command1.pl is done command2.pl won't run.

I would like to run the two commands simultaneously.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `perl command1.pl &`;
>
> `perl command2.pl &`;

..or use the perl fork() function

> perldoc -f fork

..or use perl threading

> perldoc threads

Or just use a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
./command1.pl &
./command2.pl &
```

Comment: I would fix the backticks to system() call. +1 anyway.

Comment: System call calls an "exec" - does not get interpreted by the shell. It's the shell that interprets the "&" and runs in background - so system wouldn't work.

Comment: incorrect: `system` may or may not invoke a shell to parse the arguments, depending on how many arguments you pass. Also IPC::System::Simple has some methods which can force calling (or not calling) the shell.

Comment: ampersand notation is not support by Windows' [cmd.exe]. The OP does not state he/she is working in *nix environment.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the command interpreter. In Windows you use the `start` command to just launch a process without waiting. In most *nix command interpreters as I recall the relevant notation is to add an ampersand `&` at the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [piped open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) to the process, ala

```
use 5.013;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $cmd1_fh, '-|', 'dir';
open my $cmd2_fh, '-|', 'cls';
```

Or, if you don't care about the output, [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and then [exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

```
my @child_pids;
for my $cmd ('dir', 'cls') {
    defined(my $child_pid = fork()) or die "Couldn't fork: $!";
    if ($child_pid == 0) {
        exec $cmd;
    } else {
        push @child_pids, $child_pid;
    }
}

for my $pid (@child_pids) {
   waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

(If you do care about the output, fork and then backtick?)

Or use threads (I'm not proud of this example, and I haven't even written it yet. Look up an example using Thread::Queue for something much less awful)

```
use threads;

my @threads;

for my $cmd ('dir', 'cls') {
    push @threads, threads->create(sub { system @_ }, $cmd);
}

$_->join for @threads;
```

There's also several modules that help you out with this one, such as [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm)  and [Win32::Job](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Job-0.03/Job.pm).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your skill level and what you want to do, you might be interested in [POE::Wheel::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POE%3a%3aWheel%3a%3aRun).