# How do I make two perl files communicate?

Tags: perl

So I have something like this:

**fork.pl**

```
for $str (@files)  
{        
    my($command) = "perl command.pl ".$str;
    exec( $command );
}
```

**command.pl**

```
$file=$ARGV[0].".csv";
#code that counts rows here
print $rowcount;
```

So as the end result I have 10 files launched which count how many rows are in each csv file.

I do not need help editting this code, it works (this is just a compressed version). I need help figuring out how to take the output ($rowcount) of ten files and combine it into one for further processing.

Comment: It seems that interprocess communication may be a poor solution idea here. If there are few files to process they could be done in sequence by the main thread. If there are many files it seems unlikely that you'd gain an advantage by launching a bunch of parallel processes that all try to access the file system at the same time...

Comment: It seems to me `fork.pl` would ever invoke a single instance for the first element of `@files` (because of the use of `exec`), so it seems to me you **do** need help editing this file.

Comment: Sinan, not sure what you mean, elaborate.

Comment: *Files* do not communicate. *Processes* communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of communication is solved using pipes (let me write a simple example):

```
# -- fork.pl -------------------------
for (1..3)  {        
   open my $PIPE, "perl command.pl |";
   print "catch: $_\n" while(<$PIPE>);
   close $PIPE;
}
# -- command.pl ----------------------
print rand(1);
```

It prints (random numbers):

```
catch: 0.58929443359375
catch: 0.1290283203125
catch: 0.907012939453125
```

Comment: How do I push these into an array?

Comment: push @array, $PIPE; # and don't close it

Comment: print @array; gives: GLOB(0x2350e8)GLOB(0x234f44)GLOB(0x182ce90)

Comment: Well, that's how it should work. If you want output, you need to read from every pipe in the array (using for, foreach, or map ). Reading just after open is NOT what you want, as it means execution of subcommands will be sequential, in which case << $sum += qx/perl command.pl $_/ for @files; >> does the job.

Comment: you probably want push results in an array, so substitute "print" line with: while( my $result=<$PIPE>) { push @results, $result;}, and furthermore you can handle the @result array

Answer (score 3):

I keep some utility code around for just this purpose... this is tweaked slightly to your question and including a synchronized global counting method.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my @workers;
my $num_threads = 10;
my $queue = new Thread::Queue;
my $total_ines = 0;

for (0..$num_threads-1) {
        $workers[$_] = new threads(\&worker);
}

while ($_ = shift @ARGV) {
        $queue->enqueue($_);
}

sub worker() {
        while ($file = $queue->dequeue) {
            #line counting code here
            global_counter($lines_counted);
        }
}

sub global_counter() :locked {
    #add to the number of lines counted
    $total_lines += shift
}

for (0..$num_threads-1) { $queue->enqueue(undef); }
for (0..$num_threads-1) { $workers[$_]->join; }

print $total_lines;
```

Comment: ++ for Thread::Queue. That's really all there is to say on the matter.

Comment: Excellent solution, unless program.pl is already done and you have little interest rewriting it to play nice with threads.

Comment: `system('perl', 'program.pl');` is one way to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look either at threads or Interprocess communication with e.g. sockets or shared memory when using fork.

Answer (score 0):

Compressed but won't work. I'm assuming that in fork.pl, you fork before exec'ing? Backticks capture the output of the called process, namely your prints:
fork.pl

```
for $str (@files)  
{        
    my($command) = "perl command.pl ".$str;
    print `$command`;
}
```

But rather than forking and launching processes, wouldn't it be smarter to turn the second file into a module?

```
package MyCommand;
use Exporter;

our @EXPORT = qw( command );
sub command {
   my $file = $_[0] . '.csv';

   ...
   return $rowcount;
}

1;
```

fork.pl:

```
use MyCommand;

...
my @rowcounts;
for my $str (@files) {        
    push @rowcounts, command($str);
}
```

A bit of self-promotion, but I just posted this in your other thread, which seems relevant enough: [How to run in parallel two child command from a parent one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465340/how-to-run-in-parallel-two-child-command-from-a-parent-one/4471834#4471834)

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate pipes from children:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $files = qw/one.csv two.csv three.csv/;
my $command = "perl command.pl";

my @pipes;
foreach (@files) {
    my $fd;
    open $fd, "-|", "$command $_" and push @pipes, $fd;
};

my $sum = 0;
foreach my $pp (@pipes) {
    $sum += $_ if defined ($_=<$pp>);
};

print $sum;
```

Then you can just read them one by one (as in example), or `use IO::Select` to read data as it appears in each pipe.

A hash table in addition to array is also good if you want to know which data comes from which source.